# ES module import not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make simple example of vanilla ES import export.

index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import {foo} from './mathModule';

console.log(foo);
```

mathModule.js

```
export const foo = Math.sqrt(2);
```

when I run this page I get an error

```
main.js:1 GET http://[page].net/test/mathModule 404 (Not Found)
```

---

EDIT:
project structure

- test

  - index.html
  - main.js
  - mathModule.js

Comment: Does that URL exist?

Comment: @SLaks it should be mathModule.js

Comment: Then change your import to match that.

Comment: Why add `<script>` for both if **main.js** imports the dependency itself?  Also you **must** add the ".js" extension in the `import` statement.

Comment: well it is at same level ... it should work like that

Comment: You said index.js? Is it a mistake? because this should work.

Comment: why -1 ? what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: In which browser are you running this? (Downvote wasn't from me. I just upvoted)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`import` needs a fully qualified URL.  You can't leave off the extension unless the absolute URL doesn't have an extension on it.

So judging by your examples use:

```
import {foo} from './mathModule.js';
```

---

As **[Nimeshka Srimal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3571366/nimeshka-srimal)** caught, it looks like the extension requirement varies between implementations.  Firefox is appending `.js` automatically, but Chrome and Safari expect the actual address.

I'm looking at the spec, [15.2.2 Imports](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-FromClause), and there doesn't seem to be any specification on whether the implementer should append the extension automatically or not.

Additionally, as **[ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte)** pointed out from [the MDN docs on `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path
>   name to the .js file containing the module. Certain bundlers may
>   permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment.
>   Only single quotes and double quotes Strings are allowed.

Comment: No, the given code works fine in my localhost without the extension.

Comment: this works (my habit from TypeScript to import files without extension) thanks !

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I'm almost positive that this is the case because I just created a tiny project to test whether the extension matters.

Comment: @zero298It might be the case, but it works fine in FF (61.0.1). So I believe it's a browser issue?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal You're right.  I just tried in FF and it appended the extension automatically.  I'll add that caveat to the answer.

Comment: Judging from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481851/does-es6-import-export-need-js-extension/44510307#44510307), it shouldn't work without extension usually (if the file has one). On my FF, when reading from files, i also have it working when supplying the extension, while it gives some ominous cors issue when not adding the extension (which it also gives when using a non-existing file). I vaguely remember it always interprets the file as javascript, even if there is no extension on it, but would have to read about that again aswell.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Well, appending ".js" and actually interpreting it as JS are 2 different things.  I can take an image at `http://www.example.com/pretty-lake.js` and *try* to interpret it as JS, just like I can try to interpret `http://www.example.com/inverse-square.png` as an image.  The thing is that automatically appending ".js" is the difference between a 404 and a 200 response code.  I think it's very strange that the extension is being added automatically.

Comment: As said, for local files, my FF required the proper filename aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to remove the `export` and `import` expressions since you're already including both files in your html.

```js
const foo = Math.sqrt(2) // mathModule.js
console.log(foo) // main.js
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="mathmodule.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are using node or something similar to run the script, maybe you should use a transpiler such as babel. `Import` and `Export` are "new" javascript features hence they're not implemented in most browsers

Comment: Not sure what you're looking at, but the current version of all major growers support modules. And that's aside from the fact that the simplification is specific to the example provided, and not a general solution. There are many benefits to using modules.