# Why .js [file Extension] is not added while importing a component in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

We are creating different components in reactJS,

Example:

```
App.js
index.js
LandingPage.js
.....
```

While importing this component in another component, we are not adding the extension `.js`

Example:

**index.js:**

```js
import App from './App'

// here './App' we are not adding .js
```

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481851/does-es6-import-export-need-js-extension

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Webpack config is taking care of resolving the common extensions (ie: `.js` or `.jsx`). If your project is using `create-react-app`, then this is already done for you behind the scenes.

Create-react-app already resolves the following extensions automatically:

```js
extensions: [".web.js", ".mjs", ".js", ".json", ".web.jsx", ".jsx"],
```

More info here
https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration#resolveextensions

Comment: Well, to make life a little bit easier so you don't have to include the extension every single time. Plus, in case you change your file name from `.js` to `.jsx` for example, you don't have to modify your code!

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. For my case, I used a community template for create-react-app called `typescript-empty`. For some reason, they neglected to keep in the functionality that generates the `tsconfig.json` file. This causes a problem inside CRA's webpack config, where it will essentially ignore `.ts` and `.tsx` files. Resolved by copying a valid tsconfig from another project created with the plain 'ol `typescript` CRA template.  :)

Answer (score 2):

It all done by `webpack` module resolution, a `resolver` is a library which helps in locating a module by its absolute path.

The dependency module can be from the application code or a third-party library. The resolver helps `webpack` find the module code that needs to be included in the bundle for every such `require/import` statement. `webpack` uses enhanced-resolve to resolve file paths while bundling modules.

Once the path is resolved based on the above rule, the resolver checks to see if the path points to a file or a directory. If the path points to a file:

- If the path has a file extension, then the file is bundled straightaway.
- Otherwise, the file extension is resolved using the resolve.extensions option, which tells the resolver which extensions are acceptable for resolution e.g. .js, .jsx.

**`Resolve extensions:`** These options change how modules are resolved. `webpack` provides reasonable defaults, but it is possible to change the resolving in detail.

In `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    enforceExtension: false
  }
};
```

If the value is `true` here, it will not allow extension-less files. So by default `require('./foo')` works if `./foo` has a `.js` extension, but with this (`enforceExtension`) enabled only `require('./foo.js')` will work.

Comment: It  Resolves destination URLs. Feed it a source url and the resolver returns with the destination url if any redirects happened.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.js` to `resolve/extensions` in `webpack.config.js`

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".mjs", ".json"],
  symlinks: false,
  cacheWithContext: false,
},
```