# Make TypeScript transpile module specifiers to their resolved target filepath

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I have some typescript that looks like this:

```
import { Game } from './game'
```

And this transpiles into the following JavaScript:

```
import { Game } from './game'
```

(Note that there is no `.js` extension added by the transpiler)

My browser (Chrome) tries to load the [file `game` rather than file `game.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44481851/1048572) which causes a 404.

Is there a way to tell the typescript compiler to add the `.js` extension when generating the JavaScript?

Comment: FYI, I added the .js extension directly to the typescript and got it working, but it seems like a hack?

Comment: ok, found this. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577 lots of argument over whether this is even an issue. At least I have a work around.